# Keeping state on page after refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dilemma. I receive from a controller 2 objects: an id, and an array of `long`. When the page is loaded, the checkboxes at the indexes  specified by the `"tlocations"` are ticked. The user then ticks/unticks checkboxes and presses on a "submit-btn".The button makes an AJAX call and saves the changes to the database. However, after the AJAX call, the checkboxes are disabled!

How should i approach this problem if I want the checkboxes to remain disabled after refresh press? Should I create a backend variable that changes state before refresh, and then is sent in the ViewData when the view is rendered the second time? Or are there other ways like cookies?[image]

For more clarification I added the schema. Hope it helps.

**Controller**

```
 public IActionResult Index() 
            {                     
             ViewData["tstory"]=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TempData.Get<Story("tstory"));

                if(ViewData["tstory"]!=null)
                {
                ViewData["tlocations"]=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TempData.Get<IEnumerable<long>>("tlocations"));
                TempData.Keep();
                return View(context.Locations);
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index","Story");
           }
```

**`View:`**

```
<head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/TableOps.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/BtnHandlers.js"></script>
      <script>    
         $(document).ready(function(){

            var _story=@Html.Raw(ViewData["tstory"]);
            var indexes=@Html.Raw(ViewData["tlocations"]);
            var tableName=$("#table1").attr("id");

            Initialize(tableName,indexes,_story);

            $("#submit-btn").bind( "click", function(elem) {
                var locations=getLocations(tableName);
                AttachBtnHandler(locations,function(){checkLocationTable (indexes,tableName);});
            });
         });
      </script>       
   </head>
```

Ajax call

```
function AttachBtnHandler(locations,disableCheckboxes)
{
    var result=ajaxCall('post','/Location/Attach',locations);
    $("input[type='checkbox']")
        .each(function(index,elem){
                $(elem).prop("checked",false);
                $(elem).prop("disabled",true);
        });
}

    function ajaxCall(methodType,desturl,payload=null,dataType='json')
    {

         if(payload==null)
         {
             return;
         }
         var response=null;
         $.ajax({
                type:methodType,
                url:desturl,
                data:JSON.stringify(payload),
                contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType:dataType,
                success:function(resp)
                {
                    alert("Values sent successfully!");
                    response=resp;
                },
                failure:function(resp)
                {
                    alert("Failure to send data");
                    response=resp;
                },
                error:function(xhr, status, error)
                {
                    alert("Error:"+error);
                }
        });
        return response;           
     }
```

Comment: if they only had to be disabled for the same session a cookie would be fine. If the user comes back tomorrow and they still need to be disabled, id set a flag in the back end

Comment: They have to always get disabled after the submit button is pressed.And they have to stay disabled even if the page was reloaded.

Comment: I was not sure about how to keep state logic in general.Should it be embed inside controller or cookie?

Comment: id put it in my model. If(checkboxesSet) checkboxes.enabled = false

Comment: Is the site asp.net classic, or asp.net MVC?

Comment: ASP NET MVC Core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't even saw your HTML Code but take a look at this:

Code behind

```
string getStatus = "checked";
        bool s = false;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void OnChangeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            getStatus = CheckBox1.Checked == true ? "checked" : "unchecked";
            checkbool();
        }

    protected bool checkbool()
    {
        return s = getStatus == "checked" ? true : false;
    }
```

Script:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CheckBox1").prop("checked", <%=checkbool()%>);
        $("#CheckBox1").prop("disabled", true);

       });
   </script>
```

HTML

```
<div>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="OnChangeEvent"/>
    </div>
```

It will restore the state of your checkbox its either its checked or unchecked even upon refreshing the page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I didn't even know you can call C# methods inside JS.This was my concern if it is a good practice to store state variables inside controller to be used when refreshing the page.

Comment: You can only do that using asp.net webforms (asp.net classic) and it just inserts a JavaScript which will call back to the server based C# code.